# Visual Studio 2012 elements blink and don't get selected

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

When I click on an element it blinks non-stop and can't get selected. Thus I can't edit elements properties.
However this problem appears to exist only for textboxes and listboxes, as far as I discovered.

I've recorded example.
https://vimeo.com/158462796

Comment: Do you have Kaspersky Antivirus installed? This [MSDN Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f825ae92-54d3-4aa0-9bd3-67d587d0e86a/windows-forms-designer-cursor-will-flicker-like-mad-when-a-textbox-combobox-or-listbox-is?forum=visualstudiogeneral) describes the same problem as you're having and the cause is attributed to Kaspersky Antivirus. Uninstalling is reported to resolve the issue.

Comment: I couldn't google it)

Comment: thanks, yes, I do. I'll ask Kaspersky support. thanks man

Comment: Hope it resolves it for you.

Comment: Amazing how often the answer to "my computer exhibits strange, unusual behavior" is "your virus scanner is b0rken, causing more problems that it actually solves." Even more ridiculous when you consider that malware detectors can only detect *known* malware, not novel strains---the most likely to be the cause of your damage. Not to mention the amount of time you spend hassling with these programs and the amount of money you pay for updates. A good backup strategy makes far more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated the question's comments you have Kaspersky Antivirus installed.

This [MSDN Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f825ae92-54d3-4aa0-9bd3-67d587d0e86a/windows-forms-designer-cursor-will-flicker-like-mad-when-a-textbox-combobox-or-listbox-is?forum=visualstudiogeneral)  describes the same problem as you're having, with the cause attributed to Kaspersky Antivirus. Almost all commentators report that un-installing Kaspersky Antivirus resolves the issue.